# Query to retrieve distinct records from different column values using Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've a table in oracle having multiple columns with either Y/N values, I need to display unique values based on the ID column of the table. 
Below is my table 
[image]

And Result I'm expecting is in below format.

[image]

Please guide me with Oracle query. Thanks.

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, is it Oracle or mysql? and please post what you tried so far. What is the logic to extract Y/N? If at least one row has Y, then Y else N? Or what else? Please edit your question to clarify your need

Comment: @Aleksej : Rahul understood what I wanted to ask. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: A clear question is useful not only for you, but also for future readers that can find the question, understand if they have the same need and use the answers. So, please edit anyway your question to better clarify the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group by` and `max()` aggregate function

```
select id, max(img_1) as IMG_1,
max(img_2) as IMG_2,max(img_3) as IMG_3,max(img_4) as IMG_4
from tbl1
group by id;
```